# Regex to replace between second occurance of symbol A and symbol B

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have an example string to match:

`s = 'https://john:ABCDE@api.example.com'`

I am trying to replace the string `ABCDE` between the 2nd colon and the first occurrance of `@`. So my desired output is:

`s_out = 'https://john:REPLACED@api.example.com'`

My current code is:

```
import re
s_out = re.sub(r":*(.+)@api.example.com", 'REPLACED', s)
```

But i am unable to replace this currently.

Comment: `re.sub(r':[^:@]*@', ':REPLACED@', s, 1)` might work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the match with the colon, and then prevent matching either `:` or `@` using a negated character class

Capture in a group starting from the @ sign, which you can then use in the replacement.

```
:[^\s:@]*(@api\.example\.com)
```

And replace with

```
:REPLACED\1
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF1X2w/1).

Example

```
import re

s = 'https://john:ABCDE@api.example.com'
pattern = r":[^\s:@]*(@api\.example\.com)"
s_out = re.sub(pattern, r":REPLACED\1", s)
print(s_out)
```

Output

```
https://john:REPLACED@api.example.com
```